# Why does not self focus work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Whenever a blur event is triggered from any input element, I want to set focus to one particular element.

This issue arises when I am trying to focus to the same element triggering the `blur` event.

Why does this *only works*, when the element I am trying to focus on to, is ***not*** the one triggering the event?

> **[[Issue Illustration]](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx6Cx/)**
> ***and explanation as per the fiddle:***
>
> - The element I am trying to focus to is `col0`
> - Unless the element to trigger the blur event is not **`col0`** it works perfect
> - But when blur is triggered from `col0` itself, then `$("#col0").focus()` does not work.

**Q:** Why? & What is the workaround/solution?

<sub>**P.S:** I am just trying to know the cause of the behavior and ways to overcome it. Concerns about the usability, is **NOT THE QUESTION**.</sub>

Comment: The browser, I am using is FF12.

Comment: Well I guess that when you select `col0` you have already triggered the `focus` event on it. That follows after `blur`

Comment: Are you sure you want to be doing this?  Setting focus back to the current element upon blur is denying the user the ability to go anywhere else on that web page and is generally consider horrible UI.

Comment: Indeed, locking a user into a certain element is **horrible UX**. Even if that field contains errors it's annoying. Just block submit etc. while fields are invalid.

Comment: @jfriend00, This will be implemented on a validation scenario, and i understand the effect on usability, but I am looking for the explanation of this behavior.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, Please check comment to jfriend00, and the solution is not to lock on to one element, but to focus on one element, after blur is triggered on other fields, including itself.

Comment: My guess would be that the browser is blocking a set of focus back to a blurred element for usability reasons and perhaps for some possibilities of a blur/focus infinite loop.   Moving the focus on blur is generally a bad idea.  Lots of UX issues/problems.  Virtually impossible to implement it well.

Comment: @jfriend00, Not necessarily, if the focus on blur is restricted upon a condition, it can be implemented.

Comment: @Starx: client side validation is supposed to make things easier for users, this type of locking a users input will be very annoying imo.

Comment: @KooiInc, the validation happens on a scenario, where the value of `col0` is regularly changed as per the input of other elements.

 And again the topic at hand, is the explanation of this behavior, and a fix, not where i am going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This works in FF for me...

```
$('input').on('blur', function() {
    setTimeout(function () { $("#col0").focus(); }, 0);
});
```

it is just to postpone a `UI` action a bit (after processing the blur event is finished).

**Warning:** in jsfiddle FF won't let you edit the code after you try it, once you get to the input you are stuck there until refresh

**Update:** The explanation is tricky, as it is a matter of implementation in FF (as Chrome and IE behave as you expected), my guess is that FF prevents firing related events when you are in the event handler for the same element (a thing that may potentially lead to infinite cycle), using setTimeout you are firing the event soon after you leave the handler (and even UI has a chance to redraw itself)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to keep focus on everything except the control you're on.  Try this:

```
$('input:not(#idofcontrol)').blur(function() {
    $('#idofcontrol').focus();
});
```

Comment: No, I have trying set focus to one particular element based of `blur` event generated from any elements including itself in a form.